# Installing MS Office Fonts on Windows Server

Tags: windows, microsoft-office, font

There are a bunch of fonts installed with MS Office which are not present on Windows Server 2019.  We have a web application, part of its functionality is converting Office documents to PDF.  When these documents contain fonts that are not present on the server the resulting PDF isn't rendering as it should.  The solution is to ensure the MS Office Fonts are installed on the server.

I know how to install fonts, it's getting hold of the fonts and obtaining a complete list of the Office fonts missing on Windows Server 2019 that is the issue.

Is there an easy way to install the fonts that come with MS Office on Windows Server without actually having to install Office itself?

Is there a MS Office font pack available?

Is the only easy solution here to install Office on the server?

Not trying to avoid purchasing a licensed copy of Office.  Trying to avoid unnecessarily installing applications not required on the server which could impair the security of the system.

Comment: Yes, I think the easy solution is to install Office, maybe try to install only a minor element to see if it install the fonts, else it would be to capture what font get added, and to add them manually. To use the font I would be ready to hold a licence, even if the product isnt installed.

Comment: Seems as though it was possible to run an install of office which only installed the fonts as described here...

https://web.archive.org/web/20140208105003/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2592142

Comment: However this isn't supported by later versions of Office 2016 / 2019 / 365

Comment: For Windows 2019 and Office 365, I was able install office but never bothered to assign a license (nor open the tools) - fonts are all present!

Comment: @Stan it's an option, but not a great one, installing office components on a web server can only add extra overhead and more vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use Silent Install Builder on silentinstall.org. This program allows you to install and register fonts on Windows and Windows Server.

Comment: The challenge isn't installing the fonts, the challenge is firstly determining the fonts Office has been installing, and then legally acquiring these fonts.  At one point this was extremely easy, you could use the Office Installer to install the fonts.